# Cardinality of a subalgebra of a Boolean algebra.

Tags: boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

I have been trying to prove the following.

Suppose $B$ is a finite non-trivial Boolean algebra. Consider the product $B^{B^B}$. Define for $b\in B$, $\pi_b\colon B^B\rightarrow B$ given by $\pi_b(f)=f(b)$ for all $f\in B^B$. Then note that $\pi_b\in B^{B^B}$; so consider the generated Boolean subalgebra $\langle\pi_b\mid b\in B\rangle$, and show that this has cardinality $2^{2^{|B|}}$.

I suppose one could try to establish a bijection between the subalgebra and the set $2^{2^{B}}$, but I cannot see a natural way to define it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the Boolean algebra structure on $B^{B^B}$ used to define the subalgebra generated by the $\pi_b$?

Comment: Suppose $\phi,\psi\in B^{B^B}$; then the Boolean operations are defined pointwise. For example, take $f\in B^B$, then $(\phi\vee\psi)(f)=\phi(f)\vee\psi(f)$. The other operations are defined similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to show that the algebra has $2^{|B|}$ atoms.
Now you have $|B|$ projections and each atom has the shape
$$\bigwedge_{b\in B}\pi_b^{\sigma(b)},$$
where $\sigma\in\{-1,1\}^B$, and $\pi_b^1=\pi_b$, and $\pi_b^{-1}=\pi_b'$.
Since each $\sigma\in\{-1,1\}^B$ gives a different atom, the number of atoms is $|\{-1,1\}^B|=2^{|B|}$.

---

**Edit.**
Here I justify that, according to the notation above, each $\sigma$ gives rise to a different atom of the Boolean algebra.

Let us fix $\sigma_1 \in \{-1,1\}^B$ and define $f:B\to B$ by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if} &\sigma_1(x)=1,\\
0, &\text{if} &\sigma_1(x)=-1.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that, for each $b \in B$,
$$\pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)}(f)=1,$$
because if $\sigma_1(b)=1$, then $f(b)=1$, whence $\pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)}(f)=\pi_b(f)=f(b)=1$;
if $\sigma_1(b)=-1$, then $f(b)=0$, and $\pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)}(f)=\pi_b'(f)=(f(b))'=0'=1$.
Thus, we conclude that
$$\left( \bigwedge_{b\in B} \pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)} \right)(f) = 1.$$

Now, if $\sigma_2\neq\sigma_1$, then there exists $b_0\in B$ such that $\sigma_1(b_0) \neq \sigma_2(b_0)$.
Using the same $f$ as above, we see that
$$\pi_{b_0}^{\sigma_2(b_0)}(f)=0$$
because if $\sigma_2(b_0)=1$, then $\sigma_1(b_0)=-1$ and $f(b_0)=0$, whence
$$\pi_{b_0}^{\sigma_2(b_0)}(f)=\pi_{b_0}(f)=f(b_0)=0;$$
if $\sigma_2(b_0)=-1$, then $\sigma_1(b_0)=1$ and $f(b_0)=1$, whence
$$\pi_{b_0}^{\sigma_2(b_0)}(f)=\pi_{b_0}'(f)=(f(b_0))'=1'=0.$$
Hence
$$\left( \bigwedge_{b\in B} \pi_b^{\sigma_2(b)} \right)(f) = 0.$$
So if $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$ then we constructed $f:B\to B$ such that
$$\bigwedge_{b\in B}\pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)}(f) \neq \bigwedge_{b\in B}\pi_b^{\sigma_2(b)}(f),$$
and therefore we can conclude that
$$\bigwedge_{b\in B}\pi_b^{\sigma_1(b)} \neq \bigwedge_{b\in B}\pi_b^{\sigma_2(b)}.$$

Comment: Is it enough to show that the algebra has $2^{|B|}$ atoms because of the Stone representation theorem? You can think of the atoms as singletons of a set and that gives you a power set algebra of size $2^{2^{|B|}}$ (the Stone map happens to be an isomorphism in the finite case). However, I find it odd that we somehow did not require the special properties of the projection maps -- this is the case with any freely generated finite Boolean algebra.

Comment: @MashiathKhan That's one way of putting it, but it's not necessary. You don't need Stone representation theorem to conclude that a finite Boolean algebra is isomorphic to the power set of a finite set. But that depends on what you know already.

Comment: @MashiathKhan Apparently, I overlooked the second part of your comment, and answered only to the first. You're right that would be odd that the properties of the projections were useless to prove the result. Indeed they're not, and you need them to show a the part in which I just claim that each $\sigma$ gives a different atom. It felt intuitive to me and it's not difficult to show (starting with an example to guide the reasoning, $B$ with two elements). If you prefer, I'll edit the answer to give an extra clue on how to do this.

Comment: Yes, please. I agree that it is intuitive -- however, I would like to make sure that I have the finer details right.